# Using simple/jndi registry in case of camel spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

My application context looks like

```
<bean class="com.processor.InitDataLoader"
        id="initDataLoader" />
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:vms.properties" />
        <packageScan>
            <package>com.mypackage.routes</package>
        </packageScan>
    </camelContext>
```

And here is how I am initializing the context

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext camel = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");

        System.out.println("Starting Camel... press ctrl + c to stop it");
        camel.start();
        System.out.println("Started Camel");
        Thread.sleep(50000);
    }
```

How can I use jndi/simple registry instead of default spring's Application Registry?

Somewhere I read that we can add below line to use jndi registry

```
<bean id="registry" class="org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry" />
```

but post this, on starting camel, am getting `No bean could be found in the registry for initDataLoader`.

Any other way to tell camel to use jndi route, other than initializing `DefaultCamelContext(<registry>)`?